# How can I check if a value is on dataframe? (python)

Tags: python, dataframe

I have this piece of code:

```
# movielens is one dataframe
# 'user_id' contains ids
movies = movielens_train[movielens_train['user_id']!=2][['user_id','movie_id','rating']]
movies2 = movies[movies['movie_id']==1193][['user_id','rating']]
print movies2[movies2['user_id']==19]['rating'].values[0]
>>5
print (19 in movies2.index)
>>True
print (3 in movies2.index)
>>True
```

I want to check if one value (in this case '19') is on 'user_id' of movies2. In this case it shows True which is correct, but as you can see it doesn't work at the second case because '3' is not on 'user_id' of movies2 (but is in the 'rating' column), it shows 'True'.

Do you know any way to solve this, or how to check if a value is inside the 'user_id' of my dataframe movies2?

Thanks :)

Comment: If you do this in R you can use the which function. which(df$var == '19')

Comment: uhh, what's your index? also, `19 != '19'`, you're comparing a string and then an int.

Comment: thanks @acushner , that's right, I was comparing with a grong type, but the main problem, is that I need to check, if one value is inside the 'user_id' column. There is another one ('rating'). For example, if I do "3 in movies2.index" it shows "True", but 3 is not inside the 'user_id', is inside the 'rating' column.

Comment: this sounds like you need to read up more on pandas, but generally, let's say you wanted to find all users who rated a certain movie a 3. you would do something like: `df[(df.movie_id == 1193) & (df.rating == 3)]`.

Comment: yeah well,I know I need to read more about pandas due to this is the first time I work with them, but I ask this because I've found nothing about it and in my class any professor has explained it... Anyway, I appreciate your tips @acushner, thanks a lot for your help, and sorry for the troubles caused!

Comment: no troubles caused, hopefully this helps!